# como centrar un select en htm?

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo un trabajo y sinceramente ya no se que hacer para centrar un select. Este es mi código:

```html
<p>
  <h1 id="inicio">
    Bienvenidos
  </h1>
  <ul id="Eliga su idioma idioma">
    Eliga su idioma
  </ul>
  <select style="text-align:center;" id="idioma" name="idioma" size="1">
      <option selected="selected" value="español">Español</option>
  </select>
```

Si alguien sabe se lo agradeceria.

Comment: ¿y cuál es el código que has intentado?

Comment: Primero lee cómo crear una buena pregunta. Debes editar tu pregunta con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho

Comment: lo puse pero lo paso a texto jajaj, pobre con el text-align:center en el select o en el body, en ninguno lo toma

Comment: Por que no lo pruebas de la siguiente manera: `<center><select id="idioma" name="idioma" size="1">
      <option selected="selected" value="español">Español</option>
  </select></center>`

Comment: soy nuevo en esto, me funciono, muchisimas gracias j.Castro!!! saludos

Comment: @FelipeCoggiola Cuidado, la etiqueta `<center>` se esta considerando obsoleta, aunque sigue funcionando,

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero encerrar en un `div` el `select` y en el `div` aplicar el atributo `style`

Ejemplo encerrando el `select` en un `div`:

```html
<p>
  <h1 id="inicio">
    Bienvenidos
  </h1>
  <ul id="Eliga su idioma idioma">
    Eliga su idioma
  </ul>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <select id="idioma" name="idioma" size="1">
      <option selected="selected" value="español">Español</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```